# install apache 2.4.17 or later for debian 7.9

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

Is there a simple way to install apache 2.4.17 or later for debian 7.9?
I need for http2 but debian 7.9 installs only apache 2.22

Comment: Why not Debian 8? I am using it without systemd.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install and maintain Apache httpd directly from the source code available at http://httpd.apache.org.

It is upon you to decide whether you want to manually maintain your Apache httpd or resort to the Debian packages (a practice I recommend unless you have compelling reasons for doing otherwise).